# Access slot component data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following setup:

CustomForm.vue

```html
<template>
 <div>
   <input v-model="field1" >
   <input v-model="field2" >
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 data () {
  return {
   field1: '',
   field2: '',
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Parent.vue

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <child>
   <template>
    <custom-form />
   </template>
  </child>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from ...
import CustomForm from ...

</script>
```

Child.vue

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <button @click="click" />
  <grand-child>
   <template>
    <slot></slot>
   </template>
  </grand-child>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
import GrandChild from...
export default {
  methods: {
   click: function () {
    var data = ... // get form data
    // do something with data then $emit
    this.$emit('custom-click', data)
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

GrandChild.vue

```html
<template>
 <div v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index" >
   <input ...>
   <input ...>
   <slot></slot>
 </div>
</template>
```

Basically I have a CustomForm, I want to pass the form to GrandChild.vue from Parent.vue, but the issue is I don't know how do I retrieve CustomForm data (field1, field2) in Child.vue ie how do I get CustomForm value from `click` method in Child.vue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to extract data from a slot, there are other approaches. One solution is to use Vue's [`provide`/`inject`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) feature to inject the form's data.

First, setup `CustomForm` to allow [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) to capture the form data in `Parent`:

1. Upon submitting the form in `CustomForm`, emit the `input` event with the form's data.
2. Add a `value` prop, as required for `v-model.

*CustomForm.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit"> <!-- (1) -->
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'], // <-- (2)
  methods: {
    submit(e) { // <-- (1)
      const form = e.target
      const formData = {}
      for (const [key, value] of new FormData(form).entries()) {
        formData[key] = value
      }
      this.$emit('input', formData)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then `Parent` can bind the form data:

3. Define `parentForm` in `Parent`'s data as an object with a subproperty (e.g., `parentForm.data`).
4. Bind that subproperty to `CustomForm`'s `v-model`.

*Parent.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <child>
    <custom-form v-model="parentForm.data" /> <!-- (4) -->
  </child>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      parentForm: { // <-- (3)
        data: {}
      }
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, `Parent` can provide `form`:

5. Declare a `provide` method that returns an object with a `form` subproperty.
6. Set that property's value to the `parentForm` property previously declared in (3).

*Parent.vue:*

```js
export default {
  provide() { // <-- (5)
    return {
      form: this.parentForm  // <-- (6)
    }
  }
}
```

...and `Child` or `GrandChild` can inject `form`:

7. Declare an `inject` property, whose value is a string array containing `form` (subproperty name from (5)).

*GrandChild.vue:*

```js
export default {
  inject: ['form'] // <-- (7)
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bardeen-1mdh6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FParent.vue&theme=dark)